# How to convert InputStream to int

Tags: java, string, int

I have a txt file called "max_easy.txt" in /raw folder, in this file is written a number, in this case in "0"... I want a var which have 0 as a Int value, how do i do that?

I guess this line gives me a String value, how do i convert it?

```
InputStream letturaEasy = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.max_easy);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is what you got so far:

```
InputStream letturaEasy = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.max_easy);
```

Then all that needs to be done is to convert that to a **String**:

```
String result = getStringFromInputStream(letturaEasy);
```

And finally, to **int**:

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(result);
```

By the way, `getStringFromInputStream()` was implemented [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-string-in-java/):

```
private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();     
}
```

Comment: The method getStringFromInputStream() cannot be resolved, so i tried this:

String valore1 = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.raw.max_easy);

int num = Integer.parseInt(valore1);

EasyTxt.setText(num); // the line will be displayed in this textview

but as soon as the activity starts the app stop working, anyway Android Studio is giving me no errors... why?   :(

Comment: Updated answer, sorry.

Comment: Great, now the app is working fine!
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BufferedReader` to read lines as strings from that file. `Integer.parseInt` will parse them to ints:

```
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(letturaEasy, "UTF8")) ) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
}
```